# Why is the state change not making it's way to the reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a file called Login.js in the file I call this.props.onUserLogin and pass the users auth token. I can verify that I am getting the token from the api call via the console log. When I get to the reducer I loose the value from the state somehow. I can verify that with the console log as well. I am trying to figure out why my state.loginToken is empty in the reducer.

Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../Store/actions';
import UserInfoButton from '../UserInfoButton/UserInfoButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const axios = require('axios');


class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    handleLogin = (event) => {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/token/', {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        }).then( (response) => {
            console.log('response: ' + response.data.token);
            this.props.onUserLogin(response.data.token);
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const isLoggedIn = this.props.loginToken;
        let userButton;

        if(isLoggedIn) {
            userButton = <UserInfoButton/>
        } else {
            userButton = "";
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                    Email:<br/>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} name="email"/><br/>
                    Password:<br/>
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} name="password"/><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                </form>
                <div>{this.props.loginToken}</div>
                <br/>
                <div>{userButton}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        loginToken: state.loginToken
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onUserLogin: (userToken) => dispatch( { type: actionTypes.USER_LOGIN_ACTION, loginToken: userToken } ),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions';

const initialState = {
    loginToken: '',
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.USER_LOGIN_ACTION:
            console.log('action: ' + state.loginToken);
            return {
                ...state,
                loginToken: state.loginToken,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a typo inside of your reducer - You're looking for the `loginToken` inside of `state` instead of the `action`.

```js
case actionTypes.USER_LOGIN_ACTION:
    console.log('action: ' + action.loginToken); // not state.loginToken
    return {
        ...state,
        loginToken: action.loginToken, // not state.loginToken
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cory! Fresh Eyes Always Help.